# Cannot cast Exception to ArgumentException?

Tags: c#, exception, casting

```
ArgumentException argumentException = (ArgumentException)new Exception();
```

throws:

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Exception' to type 'System.ArgumentException'.

Why can I not cast an Exception (less definition, I would think) to an ArgumentException (more definition, I would think)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's like trying to do:

```
FileStream stream = (FileStream) new object();
```

What file would it read from or write to?

You can only cast a reference to a type if the *actual* object is that type or has that type in its hierarchy. So this will work:

```
Exception exception = new ArgumentException();
ArgumentException argumentException = (ArgumentException) exception;
```

and this will work too:

```
Exception exception = new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
// An ArgumentOutOfRangeException *is* an ArgumentException
ArgumentException argumentException = (ArgumentException) exception;
```

but your example won't because an instance of just `System.Exception` *isn't* an instance of `System.ArgumentException`.

Note that this has nothing to do with exceptions, really - the same logic is applied for all reference types. (With value types there's also boxing/unboxing to consider. Oh, and there's *also* potentially user-defined conversions, e.g. from `XElement` to `string` - but we'll leave those out of it too for the moment.)

Comment: I like the `(FileStream)new object()` example. Demonstrates the point nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're creating an `Exception` object, not an `Argument` exception. You're trying to cast an object to a *descendant* of the type you're instantiating. You can do this:

```
Exception ex = new ArgumentException();
```

But you cannot do this:

```
ArgumentException ex = (ArgumentException)new Exception();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I not cast an Exception (less definition, I would think) to an ArgumentException (more definition, I would think)?

Because that additional information ("more definition") has to come from somewhere. You can only cast from base to derived when the base actually is a derived in disguise.